# ODBC write blob example Oracle C++

Tags: c++, oracle, insert, odbc, blob

Could you give me an example in c++ of inserting a `blob` in an Oracle database using ODBC API? It's my first time working with `BLOB` type so it is abstract to me. I have researched the Internet a lot and now it is all messy in my head. An example would really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a short(ish) example in C. The basic principle to insert blobs via ODBC is this:

```
SQLPrepare("insert into mytable (mycolumne) values(?)");
SQLBindParameter(1, other_args, indicator SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(size));
SQLExecute will return SQL_NEED_DATA
  call SQLParamData to find which parameter data is required for
  call SQLPutData as much as you like in chunks to insert data
  call SQLParamData again to find the next parameter requiring data
```

In example code here you'll have to write your own do_a_error() function but it just calls SQLGetDiagRec.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#if defined (WIN32)
# include <windows.h>
# include <io.h>
#else
# include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

#include "helper.h" /* contained do_a_error() defn etc - you won't have this header */

#ifdef WIN32
# define F_OK 0
# define W_OK 2
# define R_OK 4
# define access _access                          /* file check */
#endif

static SQLUINTEGER      array_row_counts;
static SQLUINTEGER      array_selects;
static SQLUINTEGER      static_ca1;
static SQLUINTEGER      static_ca2;

unsigned int            debug=0;
const char              fixed_data_source[] = "example";

#define TEST_FILE "easycd.jpg"
#define DISPLAY_GIF "/usr/X11/bin/xv"

static short insert_into_table(
    SQLHDBC *hdbc,
    typeinfo_t typeinfo);


/************************************************************************/
/*                                                                      */
/*  main                                                                */
/*  ====                                                                */
/*                                                                      */
/************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    SQLHENV         henv;                   /* environment handle */
    SQLHDBC         hdbc;                   /* database handle */
    char            *data_source_name;      /* chosen datasource */
    SQLRETURN       ret;                    /* function return status */
    char            in_connection_string[512]; /* SQLDriverConnect string */
    char            out_connection_string[512]; /* returned connection string */
    SQLSMALLINT     out_connection_string_len; /* ... and length */
    unsigned int        i;                      /* loop variable */
    typeinfo_t          typeinfo[100];          /* data type information */
    int                 type_element = -1;
    SQLINTEGER          max_column_size = 0;    /* largest column */

    /*
     *  Get the datasource name.
     */
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (!strcmp (argv[i], "-d")) debug = 1;
        }
        if (((argc > 2) && debug) ||
            ((argc > 1) && !debug))
            data_source_name = argv[argc - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        data_source_name = fixed_data_source;
    }
    sprintf(in_connection_string, "DSN=%s;", data_source_name);

    /*
     *  Allocate and set up the environment and connection.
     */
    if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, NULL, &henv) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "** Failed to allocate environment **\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
                      (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv, "SQLSetEnvAttr");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
        exit(2);
    }
    if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv, "SQLAllocHandle");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
        exit(3);
    }

    ret = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL,
                           (SQLCHAR *)in_connection_string, SQL_NTS,
                           (SQLCHAR *)out_connection_string,
                           sizeof(out_connection_string),
                           &out_connection_string_len, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, "SQLDriverConnect");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
        exit(4);
    }
    if (out_connection_string_len > sizeof(out_connection_string))
    {
        out_connection_string[sizeof(out_connection_string) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        out_connection_string[out_connection_string_len] ='\0';
    }
    printf("%s\n", out_connection_string);
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, "SQLDriverConnect");
    }
    /*
     *  Get a list of the types supported.
     */
    memset(typeinfo, '\0', sizeof(typeinfo));
    do_get_info(hdbc, &array_row_counts, &array_selects,
                &static_ca1, &static_ca2);

    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(do_type_info(hdbc, typeinfo)))
    {
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
        exit(5);
    }
    /*
     *  Find a type big enough for our gif image.
     */
    for (i = 0; strlen(typeinfo[i].type_name); i++)
    {
        if ((typeinfo[i].column_size > max_column_size) &&
            (max_column_size != SQL_NO_TOTAL))
        {
            max_column_size = typeinfo[i].column_size;
            type_element = i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (typeinfo[i].column_size == SQL_NO_TOTAL)
            {
                if (max_column_size != SQL_NO_TOTAL)
                {
                    max_column_size = SQL_NO_TOTAL;
                    type_element = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (type_element < 0) abort();
    if (debug)
        printf("\t Biggest type is %s at %ld in size, requiring \"%s\"\n",
               typeinfo[type_element].type_name,
               typeinfo[type_element].column_size,
               typeinfo[type_element].create_params);

    /*
     *  Delete existing table and create a new one.
     */
    ret = do_create_table(hdbc, "\"blob\"", CREATE_TABLE_BIGCOL,
                          typeinfo[type_element].column_size,
                          typeinfo[type_element].type_name,
                          typeinfo[type_element].create_params);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
        exit(4);
    }

    insert_into_table(hdbc, typeinfo[type_element]);

    SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);

    return 0;

}


/************************************************************************/
/*                                                                      */
/*  insert_into_table                                                   */
/*  =================                                                   */
/*                                                                      */
/************************************************************************/
static short insert_into_table(
    SQLHDBC *hdbc,
    typeinfo_t typeinfo)
{
    SQLINTEGER      len_ind[2];             /* parameter lengths */
    SQLINTEGER      p1;                     /* first parameter array */
    SQLCHAR         p2[50000];              /* second parameter array */
    SQLINTEGER          row_counts;             /* rows affected */
    SQLRETURN       ret;                    /* function status return */
    unsigned int        row;                    /* current row */
    SQLHSTMT            hstmt;                  /* statement handle */
    char                qbuf[1024];             /* query buffer */
    FILE                *fp;                    /* test file file ptr */
    size_t              readb;                  /* bytes read from test file */
    size_t              writeb;                 /* bytes written to test file */
    SQLINTEGER          retrieved;              /* data retrieved from GetData */
    unsigned int        pos;                    /* position in GetData buffer */

    printf("---------- insert_into_table ----------\n");
    printf("-- Creating rows with BIG column data --\n");

    if (access(TEST_FILE, R_OK))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't find test binary %s\n", TEST_FILE);
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    if (!(fp = fopen(TEST_FILE, "rb")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading\n", TEST_FILE);
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    clearerr(fp);
    readb = fread(p2, 1, sizeof(p2), fp);
    if ((readb == 0) || ferror(fp))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read data from %s\n", TEST_FILE);
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    if (readb >= sizeof(p2))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is too big a file\n", TEST_FILE);
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, "SQLAllocHandle");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    /*
     *  Delete all the rows.
     */
    sprintf(qbuf, "delete from \"blob\"");
    printf("\"%s\"\n", qbuf);
    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR *)qbuf, SQL_NTS);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS)
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLExecDirect");

    /*
     *  Create the rows.
     */
    sprintf(qbuf, "insert into \"blob\" (a,b) values(?,?)");
    printf("\"%s\"\n", qbuf);
    if (SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR *)qbuf, SQL_NTS) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLPrepare");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }

    /*
     *  Bind Parameters
     */
    ret = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER,
                           5, 0, &p1, 0, &len_ind[0]);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLBindParameter");
        return ret;
    }
    ret = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY,
                           typeinfo.sql_data_type,
                           sizeof(p2), 0, (SQLPOINTER)2, 0,
                           &len_ind[1]);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLBindParameter");
        return ret;
    }
    printf("\tInserting rows into table\n");
    for (row = 0; row < 1; row++)
    {
        /* a */
        p1 = row;
        len_ind[0] = sizeof(p1);

        /* b */
        len_ind[1] = SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(readb);

        ret = SQLExecute(hstmt);
        if (ret == SQL_NEED_DATA)
        {
            SQLPOINTER  val;

            ret = SQLParamData(hstmt, &val);
            if (ret != SQL_NEED_DATA)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "** SQLParamData returned %d, "
                        "expected SQL_NEED_DATA **\n", ret);
                do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLParamData");
                return SQL_ERROR;
            }
            if (val != (SQLPOINTER)2)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "** SQLParamData said it required data for parameter "
                        "marker %p, and we expected 2 **\n", val);
                return SQL_ERROR;
            }
            ret = SQLPutData(hstmt, p2, readb);
            if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
            {
                do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLPutData");
                return SQL_ERROR;
            }
            ret = SQLParamData(hstmt, &val);
            if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "** Second SQLParamData returned %d, "
                        "We though all data was sent **\n", ret);
                do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLParamData");
                return SQL_ERROR;
            }
        }
        else if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "** Driver returned a successful state for SQLExecute "
                    "buf there were data-at-exec parameters **\n");
            do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLExecute");
            return SQL_ERROR;
        }
        else
        {
            do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLExecute");
        }
        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLRowCount(hstmt, &row_counts)))
        {
            do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLRowCount");
        }
        if (row_counts != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "** RowCount=%ld, expected 1 **\n", row_counts);
        }

        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /*
     *  Now get it back to check we sent it OK.
     */
    memset(p2, '\0', sizeof(p2));
    sprintf(qbuf, "select * from \"blob\"");
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR *)qbuf, SQL_NTS)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLPrepare");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLExecute(hstmt)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLExecute");
    }
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLFetch(hstmt)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLFetch");
    }
    pos = 0;
    while(SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLGetData(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_BINARY,
                                         &p2[pos], sizeof(p2), &retrieved)))
    {
        if (retrieved == SQL_NO_TOTAL) abort();
        if (retrieved == SQL_NULL_DATA) abort();
        pos += retrieved;
    }
    if (ret != SQL_NO_DATA)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "** SQLGetData finished with a status other than SQL_NO_DATA **\n");
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLGetData");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLCloseCursor(hstmt)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLCloseCursor");
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen("out.jpg", "w")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "** Failed to open out.jpg for writing **\n");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    writeb = fwrite(p2, 1, pos, fp);
    if (writeb != pos)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "** Failed to write out.jpg **\n");
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system(DISPLAY_GIF" out.jpg");

    printf("\tResetting parameters\n");
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_RESET_PARAMS)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLFreeStmt");
    }

    printf("\tClosing statement\n");
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE)))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLFreeStmt");
    }

    printf("\tDropping Statement\n");
    ret = SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_DROP);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        do_a_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, "SQLFreeStmt");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: hey ,thanks for you reply .It was really helpful . I have written an write blob function ,no errors no errors returned by SQLGetDiagRec ,but it is not doing it's job. It leaves empty the blob field and only populates the blob name field .Could i post the code and get your opinion on it ? thanks again .Bye .

Comment: Are you sure you've a) checked returns from all ODBC calls b) told Oracle the parameter is a blob, c) called SQLPutData? You can post the code but one important bit is whether your SQLExecute returns SQL_NEED_DATA and what parameter SQLParamData told you it needed - those things I cannot see from the code. Double check by debugging or printfs etc that SQLPutData is being called. You can enable ODBC tracing of API calls in the ODBC Administrator.

Comment: I have checked all of my function returns ,i am using SQLExecDirect and it return 99 ,SQL_NEED_DATA ,i used SQLParamData returning 99 ,and then SQLPutData . I belive that this is woh it shoul return .but it only insert in table the name field ,the binary data,the blob column remains empty .How should tell the oracle thet the parameter is blob ,using SQLBindParameter ? I have this problem from a while , i rewritten the code and the problem persists.Thanks for your help .

Comment: I'm not sure why it does not insert a blob - it obviously inserted a row from your description. Are you sure SQLParamData returns the number you passed in the 8th argument to SQLBindParameter - see my example. What type are you binding for the blob - I used SQL_BINARY in the above example. How do you know the blob is not inserted correctly?